# htaccess how to remove trailing question mark

Tags: .htaccess

How can I use htaccess to strip away the trailing ? from
http://domain.com/directory/folder/?

so it shows like this:

http://domain.com/directory/folder/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no way to detect a stray trailing slash via the URI match in a `RewriteRule` (the query string is explicitly removed), you also can't check against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable because in both cases, with or without the trailing **?**, the variable will be blank. What you'll need to do is match against the trailing slash using the actual request, via the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /[^\ \?]*\?($|\ )
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

That'll remove stray **?**'s in the back of the URL. The regular expression above matches against a request, and they'll look something like this:

```
GET /directory/folder/? HTTP/1.1
```

So the regular expression tries to match the `GET` part (which can also be a `HEAD` or `POST`, other methods exist but wouldn't impact what you would see in the browser's URL address bar), then the requested URI (`/[^\ \?]*`), then the stray **?**, then the `($|\ )` matches either the end of the request (because requests can end without the **HTTP/1.1** bit) or a space.